# parse data from a network thread object to another object android

Tags: java, android, json, multithreading

I want to parse JSON object that returns from a url to a textview. for that I used class which extends AsyncTask to get the network connection. my problem is I can't parse the returning string value to my main class.

my main class as follows

```
package com.example.janitha.condd;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 final String ur ="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=keells+super&location=6.849813513872538,79.90265075223242&key=AIzaSyDQ6fVTYb1_3MmD7j3Sei4CAhbZ_eIOphs";
 String outcome=null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1) ;

        Connection con=new Connection();
        con.execute(ur);

       outcome =con.getFinalData();
        tv.setText(outcome);

 }
}
```

my connection class as follows

```
package com.example.janitha.condd;

    import android.os.AsyncTask;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.Reader;
    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;

    /**
     * Created by Janitha on 7/10/2016.
     */
    public class Connection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

       String finalData="123";
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
            try {
                return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
            }
        }
        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    finalData=result;
        }




        public String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
            InputStream is = null;

            int len = 50000;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(myurl);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                // Starts the query
                conn.connect();
                int response = conn.getResponseCode();

                is = conn.getInputStream();

               String  contentAsString = readIt(is, len);

                return contentAsString;


            } finally {
                if (is != null) {
                    is.close();
                }
            }
        }
        public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
            Reader reader = null;
            reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
            char[] buffer = new char[len];
            reader.read(buffer);
            return new String(buffer);
        }

        public String getFinalData() {
            return finalData;
        }
    }
```

each time when code executes it gives me the value as 123 which means the value that I initialized for variable finalData. what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should understand how `AsyncTask` works. When you call `con.execute(ur)`, it runs on the background thread (off UI/Main thread). Now control on your main thread reaches `outcome =con.getFinalData()` and by that time the background thread hasn't completed the task and thus `con.getFinalData()` returns `"123"` because `finalData` was not yet updated.

What you should do this is to provide a callback to the `AysncTask` and when `onPostExecute` is called, you should return the result using that callback.

Edit 1:

Your interface:

```
public interface OnTaskCompleted {
    void onTaskCompleted(String value);
}
```

Your activity should implement this:

```
public class MainActivity implements OnTaskCompleted {
    //...

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ...
        Connection con=new Connection(MainActivity.this);
        con.execute(url);
   ...
   }

   @Override
   public onTaskCompleted(String value) {
       // you will receive the data here.
   }
}
```

Changing constructor of the `AsyncTask`:

```
public class Connection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
       private OnTaskCompleted listener;

       public Connection(OnTaskCompleted listener){
           this.listener=listener;
       }
       String finalData="123";
       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
```

Return data `onPostExecute`:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if(listener!=null) {
         listener.onTaskCompleted(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: where should I make a call back? I am sorry I am really new to thread programming

Comment: @jan, check the updated answer, I have added callback implementation.